# How to write a series using C for loop?

Tags: c

I am having trouble with writing code for a series, I believe it is something with my if statement but I am stumped. The series is supposed to be

[image: ((-1)^(n+1))*n^2]

but I keep getting the wrong output. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n,t=1,nextTerm,sum=0,i;

int main() {
    printf("Enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if (t%2 == 0) {
            nextTerm = 1;
        }
        else {
            nextTerm = -1;
        }
        t=nextTerm*(t*t);
        sum=sum+t;
    }
    printf("The value of the series is: %d\n",sum);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* the code? Perhaps you should take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), and learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line.

Comment: From what I could understand, you should write a function that accepts `n`, computes and returns `((-1)^(n+1))*n^2`. now call this function with the desired value of `n`.

Comment: Also, please don't use global variables, even in simple programs like this. Bad habits like that tend to stick, better learn good habits from the beginning (and hope that those stick instead).

Comment: What output do you expect and what output do you get?

Comment: You have all your variables mixed up. Check them carefully.

Comment: `(t*t)` should be `(i*i)`.

Comment: I think `if(t%2 == 0)`should be `if (i%2 == 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `i+1` instead of `i` and replace `t*t` with `i*i`. You don't need any extra variable like `t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,nextTerm,sum=0,i;
    printf("Enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if ((i+1)%2 == 0) 
           nextTerm = 1;
        else
           nextTerm = -1;
        sum=sum+(nextTerm*i*i);
    }
    printf("The value of the series is: %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

**Series be like this:**

```
1, -4, 9, -16, ...
```

**Output:**

```
Enter an integer number:4

The value of the series is: -10
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood it correctly, it should be something like this?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {   
    int n,t=1,firstPart,sum=0,i;

    printf("Enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("The serie is: \n");

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if (i%2 == 0) {
            firstPart = 1;
        }
        else {
            firstPart = -1;
        }

        t=firstPart*(i*i);
        printf(" %d\t ", t);
        sum=sum+t;
    }

    printf("\nThe value of the series is: %d\n",sum);
    return (0);
}
```

for n = 4, the series is:

-1 /  4    /  -9   /  16   /

and the sum is 10

Comment: You generate a wrong series for given problem. It should be 1, -4, 9, -16.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `(t*t)` with `(i*i)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n,i,sum=0,nextTerm,t;
    printf("Enter an integer number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        if (t%2 == 0) {
            nextTerm = 1;
        }
        else {
            nextTerm = -1;
        }
        t=nextTerm*(i*i);
        sum=sum+t;
    }
    printf("The value of the series is: %d\n",sum);
    return (0);
}
```

Output -

```
Enter an integer number:4

The value of the series is: -10
```

Comment: Using `i` in `if (i%2 == 0)` would be easier to understand/ more obvious. Just optics, yours works fine, too.

Comment: Your ip and op are correct but your code shows wrong output.